# Как подключить 2 приложения Django к одной таблице в базе данных?

Tags: mysql, django

При миграции MySQL бд каждое приложение создало свою таблицу в базе данных. Мне нужно что бы одно приложение заносило информацию в таблицу, а второе читало ее и выводило (только учу Django и не знаю рационально так использовать приложения или нет). В моделях первого и второго приложения код одинаковый

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у тебя действительно стоит такая задача, чтобы было два приложения, то попробуй посмотреть в сторону документации, там описано нечто похожее правда при переходе со старой базы в новую, для простоты миграции лучше делать из одного приложенния. Ссылка на доку
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте к своему ответу дополнительную информацию. В текущем виде ваше решение сложно понять.